# Can react router have a route with multiple option parameters where (e.g.) both are required, or none

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Using react-router-dom I have a route like so:

```
<Route path='/:year?/:month?' component={ThingUsingYearAndMonth} />
```

But really I want BOTH year and month to exist (e.g. `/2018/Dec` or `/2017/Jan`) or neither.  I.e. just /2018 wouldn't match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably handle that using two routes -- one for when both are provided and one for when neither are provided:

```
<Route path='/:year/:month' component={ThingUsingYearAndMonth} />
<Route path='/' exact component={ThingUsingYearAndMonth} />
```

Comment: I think this is best probably.  In the `/` case it's going to default to current month anyway when those are undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Try providing explicit parameters with regex:

```
<Route path='/:year(\\d{4})?/:month([A-Za-z]+)?' component={ThingUsingYearAndMonth} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any mechanism provided by the `react-router-dom` to validate the route params. You are better off creating your own Higher Order Component and validate the route params in it. Or you can use regex to validate your params in the route itself.

Comment: Thanks! New to react - but I was also wondering how to do that and then redirect on invalid ones. Based on the above google found me https://www.codementor.io/sahilmittal/using-higher-order-components-for-authenticated-routing-i1hcp6pc6 which looks like a good starting point